# mySQL: Insert query value in Insert query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert a new tag into my table. Tags have a column called type which is an int. I also have a table that maps type from a string to an int.

```
let sql = `INSERT INTO tag (name, type) VALUES (${tag.name}, SELECT id FROM tag_type WHERE type=${tag.type});`
```

This gives me a syntax error. What is the correct way to insert a value from another table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your query. Firstly, since `tag.type` and `tag.name` are strings, they must be enclosed in single quotes in the `SELECT`. Secondly, subqueries must be enclosed in parentheses `()`. This should work:

```
let sql = `INSERT INTO tag (name, type) VALUES ('${tag.name}', (SELECT id FROM tag_type WHERE type='${tag.type}'));`
```

It's cleaner to write this sort of query using an [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) query, adding the value as a constant to the `SELECT`:

```
let sql = `INSERT INTO tag (name, type) SELECT '${tag.name}', id FROM tag_type WHERE type='${tag.type}';`
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the structure of the second example. When I run the query I think it is trying to use `tag.name` as a column. For example if `name = english` and `type = language` I get the error `Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'english' in 'field list'`. Is there a special way to add it as a constant?

Comment: @BoneJones sorry about that I accidentally omitted the quotes around `${tag.name}` in each of the queries. See my edit.

Comment: Is there a way I can conveniently throw an error if the type in `SELECT '${tag.name}', id FROM tag_type WHERE type='${tag.type}'` is not in the tag_type table?

Comment: @BoneJones in the first form, if you make the `type` column `NOT NULL` you will get an error if the `SELECT` fails as you would be trying to insert a `NULL` value into a `NOT NULL` column. For the second form, you can check the for the number of affected rows being 0 (in `node.js` you would use `result.affectedRows == 0`)